# Is there an easy way to alias PowerShell in cmd?

Tags: powershell, windows-command-prompt, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

Whenever I login to my servercore server, the first thing i usually do is this:

```
powershell start-process powershell -verb runas
```

It's a little annoying to always write this whole sentence. can I somehow shorten this?

```
powershell start powershell -v runas
```

is the shortest version I can come up with. Is there a way to alias `powershell` to `ps` or `posh` or something in cmd? Or any other command that does this and doesn't take such a long time to write?

Thanks!

Comment: one idea that just came to my mind is `function posh { start powershell -v runas }` in my powershell profile so I can do `powershell posh` in cmd, but sometimes I don't want a PS Profile on my server, so any other ideas are more than welcome

Comment: If you start in cmd.exe and you always want to start an elevated PowerShell prompt, you could create a `.cmd` batch file that contains the line and distribute it via Group Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could autostart a batch with the command

```
@powershell start-process powershell -verb runas
```

There is no need for 3rd party tools - use doskey.exe.

```
doskey PS=powershell start-process powershell -verb runas
```

And only enter PS in future. To have doskey available in every cmd instance insert an autorun in registry (and store your preferred macros in a file to preload)

I use this batch to automate this. If not present it creates a file aliases.txt in the userprofile folder, runs doskey with this file and generates a registry autorun entry to do this when cmd.exe runs.

```
@Echo off
Set "Aliases=%UserProfile%\Aliases.txt"
If Not Exist "%Aliases%" (
  Echo CDD=CD /D $*
  Echo X=Exit /b 0
  Echo clear=cls
  Echo Alias=Doskey $*
  Echo Aliases=Doskey /MACROS:ALL
  Echo mc=far
  Echo PS=powershell start-process powershell -verb runas
)>"%Aliases%"
Doskey /Macrofile="%Aliases%"

Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
Reg ADD "%Key%" /f /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "Doskey /MacroFile=\"%Aliases%\""
```

Answer (score 1):

There are keyboard macro tools you can run on your workstation. A hotkey can be programmed to send any key sequence you like, even if the active window is a RDP, SSH, whatever to a remote system. Specific product recommendations are prohibited on the site, unsure if this next sentence will be flagged/removed. If you look around, you may find one that can be abbreviated AHK.

Comment: I don't think production recommendations, [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) in this case, are prohibited.... It's that *questions* which are merely production recommendation requests are off-topic. Please  do recommend a product if you feel it would benefit or suppliment your answer.